# How to change the limit numbers of gerrit query

Tags: gerrit

when I was using gerrit query `ssh -p 29418 exueniu@selngerrit.mo.sw.xxx.se gerrit query --start 10 status:merged 'project:wmr/wmr_xxx'` it will only give me at most 500 results.

> type: stats
>   rowCount: 500
>   runTimeMilliseconds: 196
>   moreChanges: true

I have tried to use the parameter limit and set the limit to 700.

`ssh -p 29418 exueniu@selngerrit.mo.sw.XXXX.se gerrit query --start 10 status:merged 'project:wmr/wmr_XXX' limit:700` it doesn't work, we still get only 500 results, anyone know how to get more results?

Answer (score 2):

There's an internal 500 limit which is not explained very well in the [Gerrit documentation](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/cmd-query.html):

> If no limit is supplied an internal default limit is used to prevent
>   explosion of the result set

To bypass this limit you need to have the [Query Limit](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/access-control.html#capability_queryLimit) permission:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

/changes/?o=CURRENT_REVISION&o=CURRENT_COMMIT&q=status:merged+after:2021-03-01+before:2021-03-25&start=0

/changes/?o=CURRENT_REVISION&o=CURRENT_COMMIT&q=status:merged+after:2021-03-01+before:2021-03-25&start=500

/changes/?o=CURRENT_REVISION&o=CURRENT_COMMIT&q=status:merged+after:2021-03-01+before:2021-03-25&start=1000

---

when the project changes over 500, param: n or limit does not work!

you can try this with param 'start', if start is null, the result limit is 500.
the /changes is query by pagenation.

when you receive the response,the last index of result have one param:_more_change;
when '_more_change' equals true,it means have next page. otherwise it reach to the end.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5xBE.png